# Javascript Check if element onload contains string

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it possible to detect if element contains "onload" attribute and if its value contain some string?

I've dig Google a lot didn't find answer to this question.

Thanks
Moti

Comment: But you got an element and tried something ? HTML some js ?

Comment: How did you google so you couldn't find a solution? I assume google "get element attribute javascript"? If getAttribute method doesn't work for you then you are asking wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var func = document.getElementById("elem").onload;
var body = func.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1].trim();
alert(body);
```

```html
<element id="elem" onload="test" />
```